# Camera with auto focus

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an app in android studio and I need to take a picture of text, that's means the the picture need to be on focus.

Right now I can take pictures but they're not in focus and I can't read the text. I thought using the auto focus but I didn't found a tutorial that teaches how to do that.

My code is:

```
public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView camView;
    Button camBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

        camView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.camView);
        camBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.camBTN);

        camBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
         camView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this relates to socket ?

Comment: It was title of a draft that I forgot to change fixed it now

Comment: You can't do anything because your camera activity is separate app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the features in your Manifest file. Check if auto-focus works after adding these lines in your Manifest file.

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
    android:required="false" />
```